# Casting discriminated union without common ancestor

Tags: f#

I have discriminated union:

```
type Attribute =
    | A of o : A
    | B of o : B
    | None
```

I have a function wich return a list of Attributes (Attribute list).

```
let attributes = foo some another
```

I need a create function which gets a list of Attributes and return Result type where:

```
type Result =
{
    a : A[]
    b : B[]
}
```

Th function must get each element of list and add it to corresponding array of Result type.

Here is my attempt:

```
let justDoIt (attributes : Attribute list) : Result = 

   let result =  { 
                    a = Array.empty;  
                    b = Array.empty 
                  }

    let accumulate (a : Attribute) (accum : Result) : Result =
        match a with
        | A o -> o :?> A |> Array.append accum.a                         
        accum

    let rec foo (attributes : Attribute list) (accum : Result) : Result =
        match attributes with
        | [] -> accum
        | hd::tail -> foo tail (accumulate hd accum)             

    foo attributes result
```

I have the problem in the `accumulate` function when I am tying to cast discriminated union to specific type.

Is there a way to it or it will be beter to solve this task with different approach ?

**Updated**:

```
type A = 
 {
    Some : int
 }

type B = 
 {
    Another : string
 }
```

Comment: Do you have somewhere another definitions (not cases of the `Attribute` discriminated union) for types A and B? Your `type Attribute = ...` is not compiling as written here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Seq.fold` (rather than writing the recursive processing yourself). It looks nicer if you store the results as lists, because you can just append new elements using the `::` operator:

```
let justDoIt attributes = 
  attributes |> Seq.fold (fun ({ a = alist; b = blist } as st) it ->
    match it with
    | A a -> { st with a = a :: alist }
    | B b -> { st with b = b :: blist }
    | _ -> st ) { a = []; b = [] }
```

Comment: Thanks! With lists things look better

Comment: One additional little question. I need to return the result of function as result of WCF method.  When I have used arrays they correspond to C# arrays. But when I changed type to lists it generates FSharpListOf... objects on the client side. What is the best to do in this case? Write a wrapper function to convert Result with lists to Result2 with arrays?

Comment: Yes.. Alternatively, you could just use a tuple of lists as the state and then, once you're done, turn the result into `Result` containing arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I n this case you don't need to cast in your function at all:

```
let justDoIt (attributes : Attribute list) : Result = 

  let result =  { 
                   a = Array.empty;  
                   b = Array.empty 
                 }

  let accumulate (a : Attribute) (accum : Result) : Result =
       match a with
       | A o -> { accum with a = Array.append (accum.a) [|o|] } // don't need to cast as 'o' is already of type 'A'
       | B o -> { accum with b = Array.append (accum.b) [|o|] } 
       | None -> accum                        

  let rec foo (attributes : Attribute list) (accum : Result) : Result =
       match attributes with
       | [] -> accum
       | hd::tail -> foo tail (accumulate hd accum)             

  foo attributes result
```

However it is kind of confusing that you have cases of DU named exactly as different types. Also the record `Result` is immutable so you have to create modified record using `with` keyword.